# PHP $_POST Removing Backslash

Tags: php, special-characters

I'm submitting though a form with content like this:

```
This is a test \ or something
```

Which ends up coming through POST as

```
This is a test  or something
```

Notice the missing backslash. I really need the contents with the backslash maintained. Any help would be awesome.

EDIT:

Basically I'm just writing this out to a file:

```
<?php

frwite($file, $_POST['content']);

?>
```

I'm not running stripslashes() against it or any other transformations

It works fine on a server with magic_quotes_gpc enabled, but this application may float between servers that support and some that don't.

Basically I'm looking for a way to make this work regardless of magic_quotes_gpc

Comment: Can you post the code where the $_POST data backslashes are observed to be missing?

Comment: Are any other characters stripped such as " or ' ?

Comment: @JP. - nope, just the backslash.

Comment: If your site runs on a shared hosting, they may have some php security mods activated on php.ini

Comment: php.ini ~> magic_quotes_gpc = Off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you might be calling [stripslashes()](http://www.php.net/stripslashes). Check that your code doesn't have this function and any other libraries you may have included.